# PHP syntax error issue

Tags: php

I am getting this weird issue for my php script.

I have

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING 
in simpleTest.php on line 82
```

I am not sure why my codes not working.

```
<?php
    foreach ( $response->getPods() as $pod ) {
?>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h3><?php echo $pod->attributes['title']; ?></h3>   //line 82..this gives me error...


   <?php
           foreach ( $pod->getSubpods() as $subpod ) {
     ?>
  <img src="<?php echo $subpod->image->attributes['src']; ?>">  //this would gives me error too...
              <hr>
    <?php
            }
    ?>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you sure it shouldnt be $pod->attributes->title

Comment: @Kolink really it does tell you now?

Comment: Yup, it sure does, and it's a huge help, especially in understanding what on earth a `T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php foreach ( $response->getPods() as $pod ) { 
      echo "<tr><td><h3>".$pod->attributes['title']."</h3>";
      foreach ( $pod->getSubpods() as $subpod ) {
          echo "<img src='".$subpod->image->attributes['src']."'><hr>";
      }
}?>
```

Coderabbi's right, there was a missing curly.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a closing curly brace for the outer foreach loop.